# Как проверить совпадает ли значение элемента датафрейма любому из элементов списка

Tags: python

задача такая есть dataframe `Positions` состоящий из одного столбца, длинной 70471 строк, который содержит занимаемые должности типа "член Совета директоров, начальник юридического управления" и так далее.
И есть список "ключей" `Keysl` длинной 1124 строки и содержит также названия должностей.

Нужно проверить совпадает ли каждый элемент из датафрейма любому из элементов списка. Нужно проверить на полное совпадение и частичное совпадение.

Входные данные:

Position DataFrame

| Position |
| --- |
| член Совета директоров |
| начальник юридического управления |
| старший помощник прокурора |
| заместитель начальника отдела регистрации и у... |
| Генеральный директор |
| Первый вице - президент, Президент |
| Начальник Управления, Финансовое Управление |
| Начальник Управления, Управление Планирования... |
| Начальник Управления, Управление Планирования... |
| Начальник Отдела - Заместитель Начальника Упр... |

Keysl

```
Keysl = ['Руководитель Администрации Президента Российской Федерации', 'Первый заместитель Руководителя Администрации Президента Российской Федерации', 'Заместитель Руководителя Администрации Президента Российской Федерации', 'Заместитель Руководителя Администрации Президента Российской Федерации - пресс-секретарь Президента Российской Федерации', 'Прокурор']
```

Я хочу получить Dataframe выглядещий в идеале как то так:

| Position | Goverment |
| --- | --- |
| член Совета директоров | - |
| начальник юридического управления | - |
| старший помощник прокурора | Прокурор |
| заместитель начальника отдела регистрации и у... | - |
| Генеральный директор | - |
| Первый вице - президент, Президент | - |
| Начальник Управления, Финансовое Управление | - |
| Начальник Управления, Управление Планирования... | - |
| Начальник Управления, Управление Планирования... | - |
| Начальник Отдела - Заместитель Начальника Упр... | - |

Я пыталась сделать следующее:

```
def is_part_in_list(str_, words):
    for word in words:
        if word.lower() in str_.lower():
            return True
    return False

l =[]
for i in range(0,len(Positions.iloc[:,0])):
    words = Keysl
    str_ = str(Positions.iloc[i,:])
    l.append(is_part_in_list(str_, words))
    OUTPUT = pd.DataFrame(l)
```

Получила

```
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Также пыталась делать вот так:

```
for i in range(0,len(Positions.iloc[10,0])):
    if str(Positions.iloc[i,0]) in Keysl:
        print("Yep")
    else:
        print("Nop")
```

Опять получилаа ту же ошибку

```
IndexingError: Too many indexers
```

Скажите пожалуйста как можно решить эту проблему и можно ли вообще?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: “частичное совпадение” можно понимать по-разному, поэтому стоит описать в вопросе как его понимаете именно вы.

Comment: Сдаётся мне у вас `Positions` это не датафрейм, а `Series`, иначе ошибки такие непонятны.

Comment: Исправила, спасибо большое за коментарии, CrazyElif, вы правы, я не заметила, исправила на Dataframe заработало

Comment: Так не понятно, вы вопрос свой решили или нет?

Comment: @Polina Вы уже, конечно, не новичок, но осмелюсь напомнить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: к сожалению все еще нет, но ошибку выдавать перестало